# Rich:calendar Date Pattern validation

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Following is the code of rich:calendar I am using in a JSF form

```
<rich:message for="biddate" id="bidDateErrMsg"/>
<rich:calendar id="biddate" showWeeksBar="false" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" inputSize="10" maxlength="10" value="#{bean.bidDate}" enableManualInput="true" converterMessage="Invalid Date"></rich:calendar>
```

Since enableManualInput is set to true, Users can enter date manually as well. In datePattern 'MM/dd/yyyy', the year part should accept Integers only. But it is accepting alphabets as well.

After submitting the jsf form, rich:calendar's converterMessage is not getting shown when I enter alphabets in the last three digits of the date as shown below

```
01/01/2k13
01/01/20k3
01/01/201k
```

and the form gets submitted, which is wrong.

When I enter alphabet in the other places of the date as shown below,

```
01/01/k013
01/0k/2013
0k/01/2013
```

converterMessage is shown on the screen and form is not submitted, which is correct.

Is this a defect in rich:calendar or Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's how the parser works (in Java), `yyyy` pattern accepts any number of digits not just four. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18534451/1818198) for more details.

Comment: Then why does 01/01/2k13 get through and 01/01/k013 does not?

Comment: Because `1/1/2` is a valid date.