# Date Format validation not working for yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to validate the date in the format yyyy-MM-dd. 
If i give two digits for year (ie YY instead of YYYY) it is not throwing any exception and 00 is getting appended to the date time format on parsing the date.

I have added `setLenient(false);`, but still it is not validating correctly.

Can anyone please help me on this?

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
formatter.setLenient(false);
try {
   Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("15-05-30"); //In this line year is getting appened with 00 and becomes 0015
   reciptDate = dateFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: And why don't you simply parse `"2015-05-30"`? Is there any reason why you want another `SimpleDateFormat` than the one you actually need?

Comment: We want to throw some exception in case if the format does not match with yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534343/why-simpledateformatmm-dd-yyyy-parses-date-to-10-20-20128 See this link. You should probably define an additional check if the year is smaller than let's say 2000. Other than that 15 is a valid number for a year.

Comment: For example: `if (date.before(new Date(0L))) return false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API docs for `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) specifies, for **Year**:

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

So, you can't use `SimpleDateFormat` as-is, to perform the validation you want (note that 1, 2 or 3 digit years are valid years, and so is > 4 digit years, but I assume this to be out of scope for the question).

Validating that you have exactly 4 digits year should be trivial to do it with a regular expression.

For example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}");

System.out.println("15-05-30: " + pattern.matcher("15-05-30").matches());
System.out.println("2015-05-30: " + pattern.matcher("2015-05-30").matches());
System.out.println("0015-05-30: " + pattern.matcher("0015-05-30").matches());
```

Outputs:

```
15-05-30: false
2015-05-30: true
0015-05-30: true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Java-8 you can specify the 
minimum width of year component.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendPattern("-MM-dd")
    .toFormatter();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("15-05-30", fmt);
```

The error message is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>
> Text '15-05-30' could not be parsed at index 0
>
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>
> at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)